# Why does jquery animate() only run once, what is the solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-animate

I have a login form with a button that hides the login form and shows the signup form (and visa-vera). After I come back to the form (ex. you change your mind to login instead of signing up) none of the form inputs work or the button to show the other form.

The best I could find was that the DOM isn't updated with the new elements.
Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.or-signup').on('click', function(){
        $('.login-form').animate({opacity:0})
        $('.signup-form').fadeIn()
        $('.form-container').animate({height:'315px'}, 500);
      });
      $('.or-login').on('click', function(){
        $('.login-form').animate({opacity:1})
        $('.form-container').animate({height:'265px'}, 500)
        $('.signup-form').animate({opacity:0});
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you post something on jsfiddle.net that shows your problem?

Comment: Just curious: why do you `animate` the opacity in some cases and use `fadeIn` in other cases?

Comment: Why don't you use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` everywhere? The `opacity`-animations seem to do other (or less) things

Comment: why do you mean by 'none of the form inputs work' ? could you be more explicit

Comment: can you show us your html code please